# For loop doesn't work with bool return in function function

Tags: python, function, loops

I really don't know what to do. 
This is what I'm trying to do:
If a number in my lst is bigger than 'a' and smaller than 'b', the function has to return true. else, false. 
What's wrong here?

```
def is_in_range(lst,a,b):
    for num in lst:
        if num> a and num < b:
            return True
            i+=1
        elif num >=b:
            return False
            return c
        elif num <= a:
            return False
        elif len(lst) ==0:
            return True

 print is_in_range([1,2,3,5],0,4)
```

The function prints me true unless b = the first number in my lst.

Comment: When a `return` statement is executed, the function exits.

Comment: so how would you reccommend me to do what I want to every number in my list?

Comment: Your function is doing exactly what you said it should be doing. Perhaps you should explain better what is the expected output.

Comment: I want it to check every number and not just the first number and if one of them either smaller than b or bigger than a, it should output false. if for all the numbers the condition is true, so I want it to output true. At the moment it' just doing it for the first number in the list only. but if the condition is true and I have removed the 'return' statement from the first 'if ' condition it will return none. I cant use print and it's just for testing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your indentation and control flow is not really clear. But based on your description this would solve your problem:

```
def is_in_range(lst, a, b):
    return any(a < num < b for num in lst)
```

This is quite generic as well, if you would like to see that ALL the numbers are in the range, you would only have to change `any` to `all`.

To take it closer to what you started off with:

```
def is_in_range(lst, a, b):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return True
    for num in lst:
        if a < num < b:
            return True
    return False
```

Note that each function returns only once, thus if no corresponding value was found, only then will you return with `False`.